# Placing counters on a 5x5 grid

Tags: combinatorics

Punam puts counters onto some of the cells of a 5x5 board. She can put more than one counter on each cell, and she can leave some cells empty. She tells Quinn how many counters there are in each row and column. The ten numbers are all different .

Can Quinn always work out which cells, if any are empty?

Comment: Hint: try it on 2x2

Comment: Are the row and column sums numbers of counters or sums of counter values? Example: a row with counters 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 would have a row sum of 5 or a row sum of 15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For instance, the following placements with the different numbers of empty cells have the same number of counters in each row and column

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 2
1 1 1 1 3
1 1 1 1 4
8 7 6 5 4

0 1 1 1 2
1 1 1 1 2
1 1 1 1 3
1 1 1 1 4
9 7 6 5 3
```